# Add onClick Action Listener for dynamically created CheckBox

Tags: java, android

I am creating CheckBoxes Dynamically in an Android Class ***(Not Activity)***. So I need to add `onClick` Action Listener to my checkboxes, how to implement this.

I am using following code.

```
public class DataBaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    ...//onCreate and onUpdate
    ...
    ...
    public TableLayout getAllAlarmList(Context con)
    {
            TableLayout tb = new TableLayout(con);
            TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[maxCount]; //maxCount is the number of rows 
            CheckBox[] check = new CheckBox[maxCount]; //maxCount is the number of rows in the database.
            for(int i=0;i<maxCount;i++)
            {
                tr[i]=new TableRow(con);
                check[i]= new CheckBox(con); //con is Context class passed as argument.
                check[i].setText(Integer.toString(i));
                check[i].setId(100+i);
                // I have to add onClick Action Listener here.
                tr[i].addView(check[i]);
                tb.addView(tr[i]);
            }
            return tb;
    }

}
```

For this I am also keeping a track of the ids of the checkboxes.

Comment: what problem u are getting to set `check[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener` for CheckBox

Comment: because it is not an Activity class so, unable to write
`check[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new onCheckedChangeListener)`
as the class do not extend View Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also set any Listener to Views from non-activity class. try it as :

```
check[i].setId(100+i);
check[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

      switch(buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkbox_meat:
         // do your code here...
          break;
        case R.id.checkbox_cheese:
         // do your code here...
          break;
       // TODO: Veggie sandwich
      }

   }
});
```

Comment: then how to implement [this code in here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html)

Comment: @ShardaSingh : ok first remove  `android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"` from all Checkbox xml .

Comment: checkboxes are there dynamically.. so no chance of onCheckboxClicked, in xml

Comment: The checkboxes are created dynamically so the previous checkbox has no record for the coming checkbox, and its id.

Comment: @ShardaSingh : i have integrated http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html code in my answer and plz check it if still u have any issue then explain more what u want to do on Checkbox click

Comment: @ShardaSingh : as in onCheckedChanged method we have two params first one :`buttonView` from which we can get all information about CheckBox which is clicked by user. and Second param is `isChecked` which indicates current checkbox is checked or not

Comment: Can I just call a existing function? if yes, then how.? and the existing function should be passed with `View` class parameter. As I said I am keeping tarck of the ids of the checkboxes.