# Change in User Interface from inside CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() using non-Activity Class

Tags: java, android

I am writing a code, in which I am creating dynamic `Checkboxes` with their `ActionListener` from a `non-Activity` Class.

Now I want to change some User Interface from the `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()`.

Each `checkbox` represents an alarm. In `Database` each alarm is set with a `column` specifying whether the alarm is enabled or disabled, I need to access the database for doing that. I am writing following code:

```
public class DataBaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    ....
    .... //onCreate, onUpdate, other methods used.
    ....
public TableLayout getAllAlarmList(Context con)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    for(int i=0;i<maxCount;i++) //maxCount number of rows in database
    {
        check[i]= new CheckBox(con);
        check[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if(isChecked)
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now I need to add code in here which enables me to add Database access codes. How to do it.?

Comment: I am not getting any idea... how to even start it..

Comment: You should not create the checkboxes in your SQLiteHelper class, that is the responsibility of your Activity. You should Listen to the changes of theCheckBoxes there, and in the Activity you should create a DataBaseAdapter object through which you can alter your tables according to the user interactions.

Comment: Have a go here for how to use the SQLite database: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html
And don't put the Checkboxes and other widgets/views inside the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class - this should belong to the `Activity` and the `Activity` should call your newly created `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation.

Comment: I am doing this because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401889/add-onclick-action-listener-for-dynamically-created-checkbox)
This is the same problem we are working on.

Comment: In my opinion, non-Activity or Fragment classes should have no direct effect to the UI.

Comment: There must be some options.. have you seen a Alarm Application in HTC.. they implement it.

Comment: Why is it, that you need to set the checkbox directly from a non-activity? It doesn't make sense and it's against the MVC pattern which is quite deeply implemented in Android. HTC implements what? Because HTC does something, it doesn't mean it's the right way.

Comment: Don't add tags in the title, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information and the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot do this. Because of the limitation of Android, Android is made UI Safe. So **it do not allow any Thread or Class other than** `Activity Class` **to make changes in the User Interface.**

So the best I did was to collect all the Alarms (Data) make an `Array` and send back the array to the calling method from the `Activity` Class and make this list there.